# How to stretch a div's height inside a td when each td's div are of different heights?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that has one row and it contains two  tags.
Each td contains a div.  Initially the first td (div) has a greater height.  And the second td's div is centered vertically.

The user can push a button and new content will be added to the second td inside it's div.  This will make the 2nd td's div have a greater height than the first td's.  This will cause the 1st td's div to be then centered vertically.

How can I have both of these divs to be stretched vertically instead of centered?

Comment: This behavior is exactly what you get by default. All cells in a row must be the same height and by default that height is determined by the tallest content in any cell of a row.

Comment: All `<td>` elements in the same `<tr>` will share the same height automatically, regardless of any attempts to override this. Do you mean you need all `<td>` elements in the whole `<table>` to be the same height? Either way, you need to show your "*[MCVE]*" code and explain how your own attempts failed.

Comment: what have you tryed?  that's it default behavior of tables.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I rephrased the question.  The tds are indeed staying the same height.  It is the div's inside the tds that are being centered vertically.  But how can I stretch those vertically?

Comment: @ashlar64 so you want the div content top of the td ??

Comment: @ashlar64 [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/9vqsru8j/2/ ] are you looking something like this one ?? you can remove the "<br>" from the append if you don't need the line break after added new content

Comment: Do you need them to fill the `td` elements or do you just need them to be top aligned? Cause if it's the later, you can just use `td { vertical-align:top; }`.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is exactly what you get by default. All cells in a row must be the same height and by default that height is determined by the tallest content in any cell of a row.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  var cell1 = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
  var cell2 = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
  
  var temp = cell1.innerHTML;
  cell1.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML;
  cell2.innerHTML = temp;
 
});
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>I'm taller<br>than the next cell.</td>
    <td>I'm short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Swap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to make it easy for the same td height which is maximum. [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/9vqsru8j/). Ask me any question in comment section.

```js
jQuery(function(){

$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#added-text').append("<br>" + $('input[name="addtext"]').val());

});
 //You Dont need this equal height function so you can remove this part
  $("td").each(function() {
var maxHeight = 0;
  if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }
  $("td").height(maxHeight);
});
})
```

```css
tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td:not(:last-child) {
  color: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
   <table border="1">

  <tr>
<td>
  <div class="td_div">
    Content 1
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="td_div" id="added-text">
    Content 2
  </div>
</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="addtext" placeholder="add some text" />
<button class="btn">
  Click to add
</button>
```

Comment: This is a nice bit of code, but it doesn't address the scenario the OP says he has.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found one solution which worked in my case: set the table height to 1px and the cell height to 100%. I haven't heavily tested it yet though.

```css
table {
  height : 1px;
}

.cell {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th> Column 1</th>
    <th> Column 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>
  
    <td>
      <div class="cell">Hello world</div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div class="cell">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto debitis corporis sapiente odit voluptatem aut, quae deleniti aperiam, nobis dolore dolorem quis ipsam accusantium omnis
      explicabo quia doloremque aliquam eius magni, laudantium culpa eaque? Odio ipsam eius incidunt laborum animi accusamus obcaecati a deleniti neque, cupiditate quae iusto dolores exercitationem
      unde aliquam dolore cumque quam nulla, minus dolor ipsum amet.
      </div>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```